# Display values from two tables with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

table1

```
 id | course                                             
----------               
 1  | A                       
 2  | B                       
 3  | C                       
 4  | D
```

table2

```
id | course |     date    | flag
-------------------------------
1  |    A   | 02-10-2020  | 1
2  |    A   | 03-10-2020  | 0
3  |    B   | 21-01-2019  | 1
4  |    C   | 12-12-2001  | 1
5  |    A   | 30-12-2019  | 1
6  |    C   | 02-10-2019  | 0
7  |    A   | 01-11-2019  | 1
```

I want output to be like

```
 course | Date
------------------------
    B   | 21-01-2019
    A   | 01-11-2019
```

The conditions are 
1) only the courses of table1 that are present in table 2
2) date of the courses should be greater than today
3) only the courses with flag 1 has to be shown
4) choose the closest date to today when there are multiple flag=1 entries
5) output has to be in order by date asc

Comment: *Only the course with flag 1 has to be shown* This means "only records with flag=1" or "only courses which have no any record with flag!=1"? An example makes to think that option 1 is correct.

Comment: Only records with flag=1

Comment: If so [@Glorfindel](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/67785/glorfindel)'s [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217473/150107) is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT table2.course, MIN(table2.date)
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.course = table2.course
  WHERE table2.flag = 1
    AND table2.date > NOW()
  GROUP BY table2.course
  ORDER BY MIN(table2.date)
```

For your current dataset, you don't even need to `JOIN` with `table1`.

Comment: I tested the code on sqlfiddle and its working fine...

Comment: but I am getting this warning on my website Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/***/***/*** on line 203 ......

Comment: Thanks! In the future, it's best to provide the sqlfiddle when posting the question; you'll make it easier for people to answer the question (I had to program this 'in my mind' which is doable for a simple query like this, but not if your problem is more complex).

Comment: Your new error is a PHP problem, which is more suitable for [so] (but please check the existing questions first).

Comment: here is the working link to sqlfiddle demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9bc1/2